# My register post request keeps being duplicated

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I used the bcrypt, cookie-parser, jsonwebtoken, validator... librarys.

And I am using express, jwt, and sequelize.

The situation I am in is that when I sign up as a member, it is first added to the DB.

If you create an account again, it will be duplicated.

```js
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const { User } = require("../../models");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const {
  registerValidator,
  loginValidator,
} = require("../../validation/authValidation");

require("dotenv").config();

exports.register = async (req, res) => {
  const { errors, isValid } = registerValidator(req.body);

  let { email, username, password } = req.body;

  if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }

  const emailExists = await User.findOne({ Where: { email: email } });
  console.log(emailExists);
  if (emailExists) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "이미 사용중인 이메일입니다." });
  }
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

  const newUser = {
    username: username,
    email: email,
    password: hashedPassword,
  };

  User.create(newUser)
    .then((save) => {
      res.status(200).json({ status: "Success", new_user_id: save.id });
    })
    .catch((err) => res.status(500).json({ message: err + "잘안됩니다." }));
```

[image]

As in the postman image, the token was initially stored in a cookie and when the DB was checked, it was confirmed that a record was added.

[image]

The validation was written as follows through the validator library.

```js
const Validator = require("validator");

const isEmpty = (value) =>
  value === undefined ||
  value === null ||
  (typeof value === "object" && Object.keys(value).length === 0) ||
  (typeof value === "string" && value.trim().length === 0);

const registerValidator = (data) => {
  let errors = {};

  data.username = !isEmpty(data.username) ? data.username : "";
  data.email = !isEmpty(data.email) ? data.email : "";
  data.password = !isEmpty(data.password) ? data.password : "";

  if (Validator.isEmpty(data.username)) {
    errors.username = "유저네임을 입력해주세요.";
  }

  if (Validator.isEmpty(data.email)) {
    errors.email = "이메일을 입력해주세요.";
  }

  if (Validator.isEmpty(data.password)) {
    errors.password = "비밀번호를 입력해주세요.";
  }

  if (!Validator.isLength(data.password, { min: 6, max: 30 })) {
    errors.password = "비밀번호는 6자 이상 30자 미만으로 작성해야합니다.";
  }

  return {
    errors,
    isValid: isEmpty(errors),
  };
};

const loginValidator = (data) => {
  let errors = {};

  data.email = !isEmpty(data.email) ? data.email : "";
  data.password = !isEmpty(data.password) ? data.password : "";

  if (!Validator.isEmail(data.email)) {
    errors.email = "Email is invalid";
  }

  if (Validator.isEmpty(data.email)) {
    errors.email = "Email is required";
  }

  if (Validator.isEmpty(data.password)) {
    errors.password = "Password is required";
  }

  return {
    errors,
    isValid: isEmpty(errors),
  };
};

module.exports.registerValidator = registerValidator;
module.exports.loginValidator = loginValidator;
```

How do I fix it? Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood your question you want to put validation for uniqueness of email in database. If so you can add some code in your Users model:

```
// inside attributes definition of your model
email: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
  unique: true // throws validation error if creating instance is already stored
} ...
```

So in your code you can omit parts of finding User and checking whether emails match with requested one. You just write

```
await User.create(newUser) // if uniqueness validation fails it will throw error and no dublication would be in database
```

Comment: Oh, there was also a way, thank you.

Before I got that answer, I solved it using findOrCreate().

but why

It didn't work when I did findOne, findAll, but it's hard to understand if it works because I use findOrCreate().

Comment: Yeah that findOrCreate() also can solve your problem